# how to uninstall oracle 11g xe from centos 7?

Tags: centos, oracle-database, uninstall

I installed oracle 11g xe to test a software and have not been using it for a while. How to cleanly uninstall?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Brute force:

1. Remove Oracle software:  Find the Oracle home directory by looking around /u01/app/Oracle or browsing /etc/oratab and then rm -rf starting there
2. Besides removing the software, if you created any databases, you will need to remove the data files that hold the database data.  If you followed recommended naming conventions, look at directories /u## (where ## is 01 .. 99) for files named *.dbf and *.ctl and remove those too.

Answer (score 3):

According to Oracle in [this](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17781_01/install.112/e18802/toc.htm#XEINL133) article then its as simple as running `rpm -e oracle-xe` as root.

Answer (score 0):

If the installation have been done with `yum`, the uninstall is done by:

```
sudo yum erase oracle-xe
```